# Cannot use python variables with jinja when called from ajax

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im using Flask with Jinja 2 and try to display a table to the user when he clicks the button "display table" but without reloading the entire page.
For doing this I implemented an ajax call whichs works fine.
The problem is when I try to use this variables with Jinja like:

```
<urth-viz-table id="table" datarows="{{rows}}"
                        columns="{{header}}"
                        rows-visible="15"
                        selection-as-object>
</urth-viz-table>
```

Python gives me the error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2017 13:07:11] "POST /showTableQuestion HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in make_response
    status=status_or_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 801, in __init__
    self.headers = Headers(headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 946, in __init__
    self.extend(defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 1079, in extend
    for key, value in iterable:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

**Do you know different ways to solve this problem?**

The HTML file show_quizz.html looks like this:

```
    {% if  question_obj.question == asked_question %}
                    Die Antwort des Users ist: {{ user_answer }}            <br/>
                    Die richtige Antwort ist: {{ question_obj.answer }}     <br/>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('showTable') }}" id="csv_table">
                        <h3>Watch the underlying data to the question!</h3>
                        <input type="hidden" id="displayTable" name="question_obj_id_Table"
                                       value="{{ question_obj.id }}"/>
                        <button type="button">display Table</button>
                    </form>
                    <h1 id="didi"></h1>

                    {% if show_Table == "True" %}
                        <h2>HELLO</h2>
                        <!-- <script>console.log('fooo')</script> -->
                        <urth-viz-table id="table" datarows="{{rows}}"
                            columns="{{header}}"
                            rows-visible="15"
                            selection-as-object>
                        </urth-viz-table>
                    {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

The Python Methods used:

## used to reload page for csv table ajax call

```
@app.route('/answer Table', methods=['POST'])   
def showTable():
    return render_template('show_quizz.html')
```

## retrieving csv table for ajax call

```
@app.route('/showTableQuestion', methods=['POST'])  
def showTableQuestion():
    table_url = Question.query.get_or_404(request.form['question_obj_id_Table']).table
    header, rows = generate_table(table_url)
    show_Table = "True"
    return (header , rows , show_Table)
```

The Javascript used for the ajax call:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        //var question_obj_id = $('#displayTable').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/showTableQuestion',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)

            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact your controler is called via ajax is totally irrelevant here, you'd have the very same problem getting the same url directly.

As to why you get this error, your `showTableQuestion()` view returns a `(header , rows , show_Table)` tuple, which, [according to the FineManual](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#about-responses), is interpreted as really being `(response, status, headers)`, so Flask tries to build the HTTP Response header from `show_Table`, which is a string where a sequence of `key,value` pairs is expected.

FWIW, I never ever used Flask myself and finding this out took me about than 10 minutes. Posting your question certainly took at least 10 minutes. Perhaps you could have used this time to search the FineManual by yourself instead ?

*(I don't mean to be rude but it looks like more and more people here think SO is a free debugging service and so dispense themselves with even the most basic effort like reading the error message and the traceback and checking the doc)*.

Now I don't know what you expect from returning this `(header , rows , show_Table)` tuple from `showTableQuestion()` but if you hoped it to magically re-render the template code in your browser then I strongly suggest you take some time learning about the HTTP protocol and the difference between frontend and backend code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I was not looking for a cheap debugger actually I researched a lot on that topic. But I'm just a hobby programmer so I guess I was just looking at the wrong point.
the respons does not magically create a table but a framework that is used. But this is irrelevant for the question I asked

Comment: @EricBruch you're welcome and I'm glad if I could help. If I may give you a couple advices: Python has a usable step debugger and flask is oss so when you don't find the solution in the doc, read the source code a d use the debugger to find out what goes wrong. This is mostly how I learned and how I still learn.